# How to increase font size in virtual console (tty) in Ubuntu 20.04 on 4k screen? Or how to change the resolution?

Tags: fonts, tty, virtual-console, 4k-monitor

I am using a dell XPS 13 laptop with 4k screen and the text on the virtual console is very small. I would like to increase the font size. With the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` I took:

1. UTF-8
2. Guess optimal character set
3. TerminusBold
4. 16x32 (framebuffer only)

This seems to be the largest font available. Does anyone know if it is possible to obtain larger font sizes somewhere? Can you download them for example? The 16x32 size seems to be the largest available on my system. For a 13 inch 4k screen it is still small. Any help is highly appreciated, I am new to using ubuntu.

Another option would be to change the resolution of the tty console. Is it possible to have different resolutions for the tty2-tty6 consoles compared to the tty1 where you use the GUI?

Comment: Look for larger fonts in the xlsfonts output.  e.g. -jis-fixed-medium-r-normal--24-170-100-100-c-240-jisx0208.1983-0
  Then use that in the /etc/default/console-setup file.

Comment: the 16x32 is finally readable.  cheers